# How to send OK or Unsubscribe response to EWS PUSH notification

Tags: exchangewebservices

I am using exchange api Push notification in C#.
I receive exchange api push notification on .aspx page(C#) in Request.InputStream.

Now I Need to send OK response. But my problem is that where i Have to send this response. I mean which URL and how.
Please help me with C# code.
Below is my code :

I have see some example on google so i try to send SOAP message :

```
string oRequest = "";
            oRequest = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF - 8\"?>";
            oRequest += "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:m=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages\" xmlns:t=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">";
            oRequest += "<soap:Body><m:SendNotificationResult><m:SubscriptionStatus>Ok</m:SubscriptionStatus></m:SendNotificationResult></soap:Body>";
            oRequest += "</soap:Envelope>";


HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("This is the URL which i provide to exchange when i create subsricption. Is this wrong, What will be the URL");
                req.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages/SendNotification")
                req.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"";
                req.Accept = "text/xml";
                req.Method = "POST";

                //Passes the SoapRequest String to the WebService
                using (Stream stm = req.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    using (StreamWriter stmw = new StreamWriter(stm))
                    {
                        stmw.Write(oRequest);
                    }
                }
                //Gets the response
                WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();
                //Writes the Response
                Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(responseStream);
                string s = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Push notifications are automatically sent to the web service listener (the callback URL specified in the subscription request).
when push notifications send events to your web service listener. your can send your response (OK or Unsubscribe).
You do not need to call the url of exchange. 
You can refer:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn458791(v=exchg.150).aspx

Comment: This is quite simple. Just use method type HttpResponseMessage    and return it. As -                return new HttpResponseMessage()
            {
                Content = new StringContent(RESPONSE_OK, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml")
            };

Comment: This will automatically send response where we get this call.    Here RESPONSE_OK is string. And value in XML format. RESPONSE_OK = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><soap:Envelope><soap:Body><SendNotificationResult xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/">SubscriptionStatus>Ok</SubscriptionStatus></SendNotificationResult></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";